# Adicionar Faixa abaixo da AppBar

Tags: flutter

Estou usando código abaixo para gerar um SideMenuBar. Preciso colocar, logo abaixo da AppBar uma outra faixa de cor Azul escuro, porém quando troco a Row (do Body) para colocar uma Column e assim colocar outra faixa apresenta erro de Overflow. Alguém sabe como fazer isso?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:easy_sidemenu/easy_sidemenu.dart';

void main(){
  runApp(
    const MaterialApp(
      home: HomePage(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    )
  );
}
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

  PageController page = PageController();
  SideMenuController sideMenu = SideMenuController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    sideMenu.addListener((p0) {
      page.jumpToPage(p0);
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Exemplo'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
      ),
      body: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          SideMenu(
            controller: sideMenu,
            style: SideMenuStyle(
              displayMode: SideMenuDisplayMode.auto,
              hoverColor: Colors.blue[100],
              selectedColor: Colors.lightBlue,
              selectedTitleTextStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              selectedIconColor: Colors.white,
            ),
            title: Column(
              children: [
                ConstrainedBox(
                  constraints: const BoxConstraints(
                    maxHeight: 150,
                    maxWidth: 150,
                  ),
                  child: Text('Texto')
                ),
                const Divider(
                  indent: 8.0,
                  endIndent: 8.0,
                ),
              ],
            ),
            footer: const Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Text(
                'mohada',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
              ),
            ),
            items: [
              SideMenuItem(
                priority: 0,
                title: 'Dashboard',
                onTap: (page, _) {
                  sideMenu.changePage(page);
                },
                icon: const Icon(Icons.home),
                badgeContent: const Text(
                  '3',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                ),
                tooltipContent: "This is a tooltip for Dashboard item",
              ),
              SideMenuItem(
                priority: 1,
                title: 'Users',
                onTap: (page, _) {
                  sideMenu.changePage(page);
                },
                icon: const Icon(Icons.supervisor_account),
              ),
              SideMenuItem(
                priority: 2,
                title: 'Files',
                onTap: (page, _) {
                  sideMenu.changePage(page);
                },
                icon: const Icon(Icons.file_copy_rounded),
                trailing: Container(
                    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.amber,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(6))),
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                          horizontal: 6.0, vertical: 3),
                      child: Text(
                        'New',
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 11, color: Colors.grey[800]),
                      ),
                    )),
              ),
              SideMenuItem(
                priority: 3,
                title: 'Download',
                onTap: (page, _) {
                  sideMenu.changePage(page);
                },
                icon: const Icon(Icons.download),
              ),
              SideMenuItem(
                priority: 4,
                title: 'Settings',
                onTap: (page, _) {
                  sideMenu.changePage(page);
                },
                icon: const Icon(Icons.settings),
              ),
              const SideMenuItem(
                priority: 7,
                title: 'Exit',
                icon: Icon(Icons.exit_to_app),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: PageView(
              controller: page,
              children: [
                Container(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  child: const Center(
                    child: Text(
                      'Dashboard',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 35),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  child: const Center(
                    child: Text(
                      'Users',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 35),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  child: const Center(
                    child: Text(
                      'Files',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 35),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  child: const Center(
                    child: Text(
                      'Download',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 35),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  child: const Center(
                    child: Text(
                      'Settings',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 35),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  child: const Center(
                    child: Text(
                      'Only Title',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 35),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  child: const Center(
                    child: Text(
                      'Only Icon',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 35),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Não sei se é exactamente isto de que setás á procura, mas eis uma possivel solução.

A biblioteca **easy_sidemenu** parece funcionar apenas quando o tamanho do parent é fixo, o que obriga a adicionar um widget do tipo **Flexible** sobre a **Row**.

A ideia de criar uma coluna para poder separar o conteudo do novo header e o conteúdo atual está correto, no entanto determonados elementos do como o **Flexible**, obrigam a que o elemento acima (**parent**) seja um **Flex**, uma **Column** ou um **Row**. Caso contrário existe um erro de Layout, por falta de informação no calculo do tamanho dos widgets no interface.

Edit: código completo

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:easy_sidemenu/easy_sidemenu.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MaterialApp(
    home: HomePage(),
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  ));
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  PageController page = PageController();
  SideMenuController sideMenu = SideMenuController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    sideMenu.addListener((p0) {
      page.jumpToPage(p0);
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Exemplo'),
          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            SizedBox(
                height: 50,
                child: Container(
                  width: double.infinity,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.blue),
                  child: const Center(
                      child: Text(
                    "Your Custom Header",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 20,
                    ),
                  )),
                )),
            Flexible(
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  SideMenu(
                    controller: sideMenu,
                    style: SideMenuStyle(
                      displayMode: SideMenuDisplayMode.auto,
                      hoverColor: Colors.blue[100],
                      selectedColor: Colors.lightBlue,
                      selectedTitleTextStyle:
                          const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                      selectedIconColor: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    title: Column(
                      children: [
                        ConstrainedBox(
                            constraints: const BoxConstraints(
                              maxHeight: 150,
                              maxWidth: 150,
                            ),
                            child: Text('Texto')),
                        const Divider(
                          indent: 8.0,
                          endIndent: 8.0,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    footer: const Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Text(
                        'mohada',
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
                      ),
                    ),
                    items: [
                      SideMenuItem(
                        //priority: 0,
                        title: 'Dashboard',
                        onTap: (page, _) {
                          sideMenu.changePage(page);
                        },
                        icon: const Icon(Icons.home),
                        badgeContent: const Text(
                          '3',
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                        ),
                        tooltipContent: "This is a tooltip for Dashboard item",
                      ),
                      SideMenuItem(
                        //priority: 1,
                        title: 'Users',
                        onTap: (page, _) {
                          sideMenu.changePage(page);
                        },
                        icon: const Icon(Icons.supervisor_account),
                      ),
                      SideMenuItem(
                        //priority: 2,
                        title: 'Files',
                        onTap: (page, _) {
                          sideMenu.changePage(page);
                        },
                        icon: const Icon(Icons.file_copy_rounded),
                        trailing: Container(
                            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                                color: Colors.amber,
                                borderRadius:
                                    BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(6))),
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                  horizontal: 6.0, vertical: 3),
                              child: Text(
                                'New',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 11, color: Colors.grey[800]),
                              ),
                            )),
                      ),
                      SideMenuItem(
                        //priority: 3,
                        title: 'Download',
                        onTap: (page, _) {
                          sideMenu.changePage(page);
                        },
                        icon: const Icon(Icons.download),
                      ),
                      SideMenuItem(
                        //priority: 4,
                        title: 'Settings',
                        onTap: (page, _) {
                          sideMenu.changePage(page);
                        },
                        icon: const Icon(Icons.settings),
                      ),
                      const SideMenuItem(
                        //priority: 7,
                        title: 'Exit',
                        icon: Icon(Icons.exit_to_app),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: PageView(
                      controller: page,
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          child: const Center(
                            child: Text(
                              'Dashboard',
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 35),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          child: const Center(
                            child: Text(
                              'Users',
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 35),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          child: const Center(
                            child: Text(
                              'Files',
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 35),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          child: const Center(
                            child: Text(
                              'Download',
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 35),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          child: const Center(
                            child: Text(
                              'Settings',
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 35),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          child: const Center(
                            child: Text(
                              'Only Title',
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 35),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          child: const Center(
                            child: Text(
                              'Only Icon',
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 35),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ));
  }
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).